# Questionnable computation of Variance in R

Tags: r, formula, variance

The function var() computes the variance and for the vektor<-c(0,1,1,2) the var(vektor) returns the result 0.666 instead of the expected value 0.5.

Variance as I know it is calculated as the sum of the squared deviations from mean devided by the number of items. In this case the mean(vektor)=1. The variance would be the squared values for (-1,0,0,1) devided by 4. This would be 1+0+0+1 devided by 4. This would be 2/4=0.5

Who knows the reason why r calculates a value different from 0.5? Which formula is used? I did not find an explanation in the help for ?var.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: From the details section of `?var`: The denominator n - 1 is used which gives an unbiased estimator of the (co)variance for i.i.d. observations.

Comment: Try `{var_pop <- function(x) 1/length(x)*sum((x - mean(x))^2);var_pop(c(0, 1, 1, 2))}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R computes the unbiased variance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Unbiased_sample_variance), which is the same but divided by `n-1 = 3` instead of `n = 4`.